# How to configure nullmailer to work with gmx

Tags: mail, smtp, tls

Last time I used postfix, and it was a mess until everything was configured to send my root-mail to my gmx-address .. however in the end it worked.

This time I wanted to prevent that mess by using `nullmailer` .. however `nullmailer` as well  provides some trouble.

Here my settings:

```
sudo less /etc/nullmailer/adminaddr
myMailAddress@gmx.de
```

`/etc/nullmailer/defaultdomain` is empty

```
sudo less /etc/nullmailer/remotes
mail.gmx.net smtp --port=465 --starttls --user=myMailProxy@gmx.de --pass=someSecret
```

I as well configured /etc/aliases ... no idea if that matters at all:

```
....
root: myMailAddress@gmx.de
```

After configuration and restarting the service:

```
sudo service nullmailer restart
```

I tried to send  a testmail:

```
mail -s "whatever" root < /dev/null
```

But it failed ... I can read the following error in /var/log/mail.err:

```
Apr 20 22:20:58 desktop-pc nullmailer[4727]: smtp: Failed:
Apr 20 22:20:58 desktop-pc nullmailer[4717]: Sending failed:  Protocol error
```

So how to get things debugged now ? Or should I pick another mail provider to send my root-mails ?

**Edit1:**

Using port 587 with TLS leads to another error:
( Same when using port 465 with --ssl )

```
Apr 21 08:12:43 schwinn-desktop nullmailer[1319]: smtp: Failed: 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable#012550 Sender address is not allowed.
Apr 21 08:12:43 schwinn-desktop nullmailer[1285]: Sending failed:  Permanent error in sending the message
```

**Edit2:**

Finnaly, thanks to emk2203, I use dma(dragonfly mail transfer agent) instead of nullmailer, which I was able to bring to work in less than 5min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way GMX documents it, you have to use port 465 with SSL - you are using it with TLS, which should use port 587. So either change your port or your protocol, both should work.

Also, as an anti-spam measure, GMX **only** accepts messages from a valid GMX sender - no stuff like `root@mymachine.local` or similar.

What works is if you send a mail via `nullmailer-inject -f myaccount@gmx.de`.

I just tested my old GMX account successfully with `cat testmail.mail | nullmailer-inject -h -f myaccount@gmx.de`. You need to force an envelope with your real address with the `-f myaccount@gmx.de` option, otherwise it gets rejected. The -h option is just so only the information in the email file is used, no command line information for to: and other fields.

My format for the test mail was below. Taken from [nullmailer troubleshooting](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/nullmailer/landmines.htm), fill out the From:, To:, and Cc: fields, otherwise it won't work!

```
Subject: Nullmailer test at Do 21. Apr 13:56:57 CEST 2016
From: Yourfirst Yourlast  <yourself@yourdomain.com>
To: Yourfirst Yourlast  <yourself@yourdomain.com>
Cc: Friendfirst Friendlast <friend@friendsdomain.com>

Sent at Do 21. Apr 13:56:57 CEST 2016

Yourfirst Yourlast was here
and now is gone
but left his name
to carry on.

This is a second paragraph thats kinda long, really really long, so long that I truly hope that it does the right thing and wraps.

Sincerely
Yourfirst Yourlast
```

My `/etc/nullmailer/remotes` file looks like this:

`mail.gmx.net smtp --port=587 --starttls --auth-login --user=myaccount@gmx.de --pass=password`

If you want to use `mail` like you did, make sure that the `-f myaccount@gmx.de` option is used. How to do this depends on your MUA (mail user agent) which is behind the `mail` alias.

Lastly, I want to point out that nullmailer has an inherent security flaw. Even though the `/etc/nullmailer/remotes` file is only readable by root and the user mail, it calls the `smtp` program with the content of this file as options, so **every user on the system can see your credentials while smtp runs** via `ps aux` or `htop`. Maybe this is fixed in 2.0, but even 16.04 has only a 1.x version, and no ppa is offering a newer one.

A nice alternative to `nullmailer` is `dma`, the **d**ragonfly **m**ail transfer **a**gent. I could set it up to use my GMX credentials in less than one minute. If you use the `MASQUERADE=myaccount@gmx.de` option in the settings file, you don't even need to fool around to pass options with `mail`.

Put just the following into `/etc/dma/dma.conf`, your credentials into `/etc/dma/auth.conf`, and you are done:

```
SMARTHOST smtp.gmx.net
PORT 587
AUTHPATH /etc/dma/auth.conf
SECURETRANSFER
STARTTLS
MASQUERADE myaccount@gmx.de
```

No further configuration or adaptation needed, easy, and secure.

Comment: Thanks! However TLS / port 587 seems not to work .. I get another error. I added it to the question.

Comment: Same for SSL / port 465 :(

Comment: You are getting closer, it's like peeling an onion. Can you login to the WebGUI with this username + password combination? Are there special characters in the password? Try `--pass="SomeSecret" if you can login to the WebGUI with no issues.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the research you did. Yes I as well got dma to work in less than 5min.  Much better than nullmailer. Thanks alot for the excellent tip !

Comment: Thanks, the 587 tip works also with swaks